# Multiple sitemapnode with same url for a sitemap

Tags: menu, sitemap

I have a bit of frustrating and confusing situation here.So, let me explain this in detail.
For Menu :
I have a horizontal menu which is binded to a Sitemap(dont care about the sitemap as of now).All the menu items when clicked will direct the user to one page i.e ~/Categories.aspx with a query string.I have a onMenuItemClick event as below:

```
protected void myMenu_MenuItemClick(object sender, MenuEventArgs e)
{
    // this is the menu itself, you can iterate the Items collection if you need.
    var menu = (sender as Menu);
    foreach (MenuItem item in menu.Items)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.Print(item.Text);
    }

    // this is the MenuItem object that was clicked
    var clickedMenuItem = e.Item;

    // store text value in your session
    Session["1"] = e.Item.Text;

    // redirect
    Response.Redirect("~/CategorySearch.aspx?Category=" + e.Item.Text);
}
```

The above code works fine when i manually populate the menu items.Now i want to bind a sitemap to my menu and my problem is that all the menuitems have the same URL which throws an exception since URLs must be unique.

Here is my sitemap:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
   <siteMap xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/AspNet/SiteMap-File-1.0" >
   <siteMapNode title="DummyRoot">
    <siteMapNode url="~/Home.aspx" title="Home" />
    <siteMapNode url="~/Category.aspx" title="Track Events">
      <siteMapNode url="~/Category.aspx" title="Athletics" />
      <siteMapNode url="~/Category.aspx" title="Cycling" />
      <siteMapNode url="~/Category.aspx" title="Equestrian Sports" />
      <siteMapNode url="~/Category.aspx" title="Motor Sports" />
      <siteMapNode url="~/Category.aspx" title="Marathon" />
    </siteMapNode>
    <siteMapNode url="~/Category.aspx" title="Court Events">
      <siteMapNode url="~/Category.aspx" title="Volleyball" />
      <siteMapNode url="~/Category.aspx" title="Tennis" />
      <siteMapNode url="~/Category.aspx" title="Squash" />
    </siteMapNode>
    <siteMapNode url="~/Category.aspx" title="Field Events">
      <siteMapNode url="~/Category.aspx" title="Archery" />
      <siteMapNode url="~/Category.aspx" title="Football" />
      <siteMapNode url="~/Category.aspx" title="Cricket" />
    </siteMapNode>
</siteMapNode>
```

What are my options to make things work?

Answer (score 0):

To have a valid sitemap file you can´t have two nodes with the same Url.

In your case you have dynamic content, so you don´t know all the nodes at compile time. So, to solve your problem, you need to change the nodes of your sitemap at runtime. You can see a possible solution here: [Adding dynamic nodes to ASP.NET site maps at runtime by deriving from StaticSiteMapProvider](http://harriyott.com/2007/03/adding-dynamic-nodes-to-aspnet-site).

Don´t forget to write the full Url for each menu item. Ex:

```
<siteMapNode url="~/CategorySearch.aspx" title="Track Events">
  <siteMapNode url="~/CategorySearch.aspx?Category=Athletics" title="Athletics" />
</siteMapNode>
```